# How to copy only required rows of old DataTable to the new DataTable rows having different structure?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

I have a requirement where I need to copy the existing `DataTable` rows/values to the new `DataTable`, 
New DataTable is of custom(different column names) structure/schema as we need this new DataTable data to be exported to Excel file later.

To copy the required column values to the new `DataTable` I have created string Array which contains required column names(*columns from which we need to copy data to new DataTable*) of existing `DataTable`, given below.

```
string[] selectedColumns = new[] { "SUPPLIER_NAME", "SUPPLIER_NO", "CONFIRMATION_NO", "RELEASE_NO", "WCO_INVOICE_NO",
"CUSTOMER_BILLED", "BALANCE_TOBILL", "SUPP_INVOICE_NO", "SUPPLIER_PAID", "BALANCE_COST" };   //TODO Add columns "WCO_INVOICE_DATE", "SUPPLIER_INVOICE_DATE" later.
```

For getting the required `DataTable`, I have created a method which will be called like below by passing existing `DataTable` and selected columns of existing `DataTable` column names as an parameters.

```
DataTable _dtPrjLedgerExportData = ControllerClass.dtProjectLedgerExport(dtfilter, selectedColumns);
```

`ControllerClass` Class `dtProjectLedgerExport` method will return the newly created `DataTable` *i.e. DataTable with the customize Column names and the values pulled from existing DatTable*,

New `DataTable` additionally contain two new columns (WCO_Invoice_Date, Supplier_Invoice_Date) with default blank values (set from the code).

```
public static DataTable dtProjectLedgerExport(DataTable dtToExport, string[] selectedColumns)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier");
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier_No");
    dt.Columns.Add("Confirmation_Number");
    dt.Columns.Add("Release_Number");
    dt.Columns.Add("WCO_Invoice_No");
    dt.Columns.Add("WCO_Invoice_Date");
    dt.Columns.Add("Customer_Billed_Amt");
    dt.Columns.Add("Balance_Remaining_to_Bill");
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier_Invoice_Number");
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier_Invoice_Date");
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier_Paid_Amt");
    dt.Columns.Add("Remaining_Cost_Dollar_Balance");

    //temporarily set default value for non-existing rows 
    dt.Columns["WCO_Invoice_Date"].DefaultValue = string.Empty;
    dt.Columns["Supplier_Invoice_Date"].DefaultValue = string.Empty;

    //Copy rows to dt
    if (dtToExport != null && dtToExport.Rows.Count > 0)
        dt = new DataView(dtToExport).ToTable(false, selectedColumns);

    return dt;
}
```

**Problem:**
The above code is not working as expected it is returning Data of existing DataTable with the same structure.

What changes are required in above code to get the expected result?

Comment: Why not use `dt = dtToExport.Clone()` then just add the additional 2 columns?

Comment: There is more to a DataTable column than just a name.  You are (re)creating all text columns when clearly some are likely to be integer, DateTime, decimal etc.

Comment: @Sean T - Because there is changed in structure in the way column present in `dtExport`.. like `dtExport` contains column name as `Supplier_Name`, but for the first column we want in `dt` as `Supplier` only.

Comment: Then you will have to map the values yourself. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use this approach:

```
public static DataTable DtProjectLedgerExport(DataTable dtToExport, string[] selectedColumns, params string[] additionalColumns)
{
    DataTable dt = dtToExport.Copy(); // add columns and data

    List<DataColumn> removeColumns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Where(c => !selectedColumns.Contains(c.ColumnName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .ToList();
    removeColumns.ForEach(dt.Columns.Remove);

    foreach (string colName in additionalColumns)
    {
        DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn(colName);
        newColumn.DefaultValue = string.Empty;
        dt.Columns.Add(newColumn);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After stating in the comments that you have different column names in each table...(Seriously that's a critical piece of information lol)! The only way is to basiaclly map the values yourself for each column like so.

```
public static DataTable dtProjectLedgerExport(DataTable dtToExport)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier");
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier_No");
    dt.Columns.Add("Confirmation_Number");
    dt.Columns.Add("Release_Number");
    dt.Columns.Add("WCO_Invoice_No");
    dt.Columns.Add("WCO_Invoice_Date");
    dt.Columns.Add("Customer_Billed_Amt");
    dt.Columns.Add("Balance_Remaining_to_Bill");
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier_Invoice_Number");
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier_Invoice_Date");
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier_Paid_Amt");
    dt.Columns.Add("Remaining_Cost_Dollar_Balance");

    foreach (var expRow in dtToExport.Rows)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Supplier"] = expRow["Supplier_Name"];
        //repeat for all columns you want.

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course, because you finally override `dt` completely.  You should enumerate the rows in `dtToExport` in a loop and create new rows in `dt` and assign the values for every field you need.